# Can't set place:location on open graph type "business" using the Object Browser

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I created an app and an open graph object of type **business**.

(After creating an object programmatically) I opened the [Object Browser](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/object-browser) and noticed that the **place:location** field was empty for my object. I tried to manually enter a value for the location by clicking the edit link in the object browser, using the following value:

```
{"latitude":"40.714623","longitude":"-74.006605","altitude":"0"}
```

That did not produce any errors, but the information did not save to the object.

How can I convince Facebook to accept my location data?

Comment: did you figure this out/